# How do I copy and paste this table over to another?

Tags: php, mysql, pivot

I have a table with this structure

```
TABLE #1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
meta_id | post_id |    meta_key    |               meta_value          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234         5      thumbnail_url      http://www.domain/thumb.jpg
1235         5      swf_url            http://www.domain/flash.swf
1236         5      description        This is a description.
1237         6      thumbnail_url      http://www.domain/thumb.jpg
1238         6      swf_url            http://www.domain/flash.swf
1239         6      description        This is a description.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and another table with this structure

```
TABLE #2
----------------------------------------------------
ID |   post_title   | thumbnail | swf | description
----------------------------------------------------
5     Awesome Title     NULL     NULL    NULL
6    Stack Over Flow    NULL     NULL    NULL 
----------------------------------------------------
```

I need to copy and paste over the meta values from Table 1 over to Table 2 WHERE post_id = ID.

Any insights on how the query would look like would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE Table2 t2
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT
     post_id, 
     MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'thumbnail_url' THEN meta_value END) AS 'thumbnail', 
     MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'swf_url' THEN meta_value END) AS 'swf',
     MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'description' THEN meta_value END) AS 'description'
   FROM Table1
   GROUP BY post_id
) t1 ON t1.post_id = t2.id
SET t2.thumbnail = t1.thumbnail,
    t2.swf       = t1.swf,
    t2.description = t1.description;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cdd4f/1)

Answer (score 1):

This type of data transformation is know as a *pivot*. MySQL does not have a pivot function so you will use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression.

This process transforms the row values into columns. To select the data in this format you would use:

```
select post_id,
  max(case when meta_key = 'thumbnail_url' then meta_value end) thumbnail,
  max(case when meta_key = 'swf_url' then meta_value end) swf_url,
  max(case when meta_key = 'description' then meta_value end) description
from table1 
-- where post_id = 1
group by post_id;
```

Then to `UPDATE` table2:

```
update table2 t2
left join
(
  select post_id,
    max(case when meta_key = 'thumbnail_url' then meta_value end) thumbnail,
    max(case when meta_key = 'swf_url' then meta_value end) swf_url,
    max(case when meta_key = 'description' then meta_value end) description
  from table1 
  -- where post_id = 1
  group by post_id
) t1
  on t2.id = t1.post_id
set t2.thumbnail = t1.thumbnail,
    t2.swf = t1.swf_url,
    t2.description = t1.description;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc003/2)